# Using PostMessage to send Unicode characters

Tags: c#, unicode, user32

I am using PostMessage to send input to a flash object in another application.  It works fine until I try to send a unicode character.  In this example:

Michael’s Book

The apostrophe is not really that, it is not an ASCII 39, but rather a unicode U+2019.  By the time it is sent across 1 character at a time, it is lost as a unicode value and lands as the raw characters making up the unicode

Michaelâ€™s Book

If I copy and paste into that window it moves fine, and if I load a text file into that window it loads fine.  So the receiving window is able to receive unicode, but the way I am sending it must not be correct.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  private void SendKeysToForm(string Message)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Message.Length; i++)
        {
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CHAR, (IntPtr)Message[i], IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe WM_UNICHAR will work better.  Depends, Adobe software is, erm, special.

Comment: Why are you sending the character as `IntPtr` instead of int ?

Comment: @HansPassant [WM_CHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276(v=vs.85).aspx) uses UTF-16-bit, `WM_UNICHAR` is for UTF-32

Comment: That's not the point.  The key is whether the window was created with CreateWindowExA() or CreateWindowsExW().  Visible in Spy++ btw.  If you want an Ansi window to still eat a Unicode character then WM_UNICHAR might work.  But sure, @Mike might well have correctly guessed that PostMessage wasn't declared correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx), to send Unicode, you need to use `PostMessageW`.

It's the same method signature, just import the name `PostMessageW` and execute that.

## UPDATE

As Hans very well stated, an even better approach would be to set the `CharSet` of the `DllImport`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
```

This should cause the framework to ultimately import `PostMessageW`.

Thanks a lot Hans!

Comment: Could be it, best to recommend using the CharSet property correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant, if there is a way to do that, absolutely! I just don't see anything in the documentation verifying how to set that in the `wParam`. Did I miss it?

Comment: The CharSet property of the [DllImport] attribute.  The default is wrong in 99.99% of the cases where you'd pinvoke a winapi function.

Comment: Oh great, thanks @HansPassant! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Adding the CharSet property to the declaration solved it.  TY everyone